# Iterating rows and columns using XLRD in Python

Tags: python, xlrd

I'm using python xlrd module to parse an Excel file. Here is how the excel file looks like:

```
Title           A   B   C
attribute 1     1   2   3
attribute 2     4   5   6
attribute 3     7   8   9
```

And I want the output in the following format:

```
[
    {
        "name": "A",
        "attribute1": {
            "value": 1
        },
        "attribute2": {
            "value": 4
        },
        "attribute3": {
            "value": 7
        }       
    },
    {
        "name": "B",
        "attribute1": {
            "value": 2
        },
        "attribute2": {
            "value": 5
        },
        "attribute3": {
            "value": 8
        }   
    },
    {
        "name": "C",
        "attribute1": {
            "value": 3
        },
        "attribute2": {
            "value": 6
        },
        "attribute3": {
            "value": 9
        }       
    }       
]
```

I have tried the following but can't figure out how to create the output in the above format. Would appreciate any help on this!

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

wb = open_workbook('D:\abc_Template.xlsx', 'r')

wb_sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

values = []

for row_idx in range(7, wb_sheet.nrows):
    col_value = []
    rowval = str((wb_sheet.cell(row_idx, 1)))

    for col_idx in range(1, 5):
        if(col_idx != 2 and col_idx != 1):
            cellVal = wb_sheet.cell(row_idx, col_idx)
            cellObj = {rowval: {"value" : cellVal}}
            col_value.append(cellObj)

    values.append(col_value)

print values
```

Answer (score 7):

The iterator values in **range(7, wb_sheet.nrows)** and **range(1, 5)** are not equivalent with the dimension of input table . It seems more easy to parse the data first by column and after by row. I have a code suggestion to your parser below:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
import json

wb = open_workbook('abc_Template.xlsx', 'r')

wb_sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

values = []

for col_idx in range(1, wb_sheet.ncols):
    cellObj = {"name": str(wb_sheet.cell(0, col_idx).value)}
    for row_idx in range(1, wb_sheet.nrows):
        attrib = str(wb_sheet.cell(row_idx, 0).value)
        cellObj[str(attrib)] = {"value": int(wb_sheet.cell(row_idx, col_idx).value)}

    values.append(cellObj)

print(json.dumps(values))
```

OBS: This example run with python version > 3, make sure to import json library and change the input path of the .xlsx file.